# How to overload the '->' operator in c++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I want to write a simple wrapper around another class. A small example:

```
class MyClass {
   ...
   int someMember();
   ...
};

class MyClassRefernence{
   ...
   MyClass* ptr;
   MyClass& operator *();
   ...
};
```

If I have now some code like the following:

```
MyClassReference ref;
... // Init the ref and the pointer ptr.
int a = (*ref).someMember(); // this works but is nasty
int b = ref->someMember(); // Compile error
```

So my question is: Is there a way to use the much more pretty `->` operator instead of the `(*...).` construction?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
MyClass* operator->() { return ptr; }
```

Comment: OK, thanks. I thought the `operator *()` would be sufficient.